# Append text to existing title

Tags: c#, asp.net, append, title

I have CMS that control the page text, title meta description and meta Keywords.
I use `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plaMeta" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>`
in the code behind I use `plaMeta.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("files/xxxx"), Encoding.Default)));`
where xxxx is a file stores the title meta description and meta Keywords.
I have several pages that only on the first I need the text that is on other file, I want to use the some title meta description and meta Keywords on the other pages, but add the the page number of the page I am on the title will something like "page name - page 2".

I tried to append text with the code

```
head1.title += head1.title + " - page 2"
```

but it did not work.

I do not want to open file for every page just for the meta and titles.
Is it possible?

(I tried to search, but did not find anything, maybe my keywords were not good)

Comment: what is the result of what you tried? is it just 
"head1.title" ?

Comment: When you use the += operator, you needn't add the head1.title part again, it does it for you. So 1 thing I can help you with is the following:

Change head1.title += head1.title + " - page 2" to head1.title += " - page 2"

Other than that the question isn't very clear, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem, the problem is that the appending not working, I keep have the old title that come with the file.
the part of " - page 2" do not append.
Instead of having for example Bricks - page 2, I keep having Bricks.

@Elior, yes I keep having the head1.title it is not changing.

(By the way, how do I enable option the get email when someone response to the post?, I search the history to find this post)

Comment: I don't know how to enable this option, but you don't have to search the history, just enter to your profile and look at the questions part

Comment: Thanks Elior, but I do have my profile on my favorites but I added ti

Comment: and for the question, I don't familiar with asp.net and I don't know if it's a good solution but just to check try to write 
header1.title = new string (header.title + " - page 2");